# How to get Subdiv Surface to not miss the vertices?

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm trying to create really accurate external surfaces for an airplane fuselage with minimal geometry.  I want to use the Modifier + Subdivision Surface but the new mesh is smoothed so that it no longer passes through the vertices.

I create cross sections (one half, I'll mirror them later) using a Bezier curve.  Then I use a cube and start adding edge loops.  Then I move the vertices onto the Bezier Curve.

When I add the Subdiv Surface the surface is nicely smoothed, but the surface lands "inside" my desired surface, missing my vertices altogether.

How do I get Subdiv Surface to honor my geometry by always passing through the vertices?[image: Subdiv Surface Misses Vertices]

Comment: Sounds like you either need more vertex or subdivision based modelling is not really the adequate tool for what you are trying to do. You can turn on the *Subdivision Surface* modifier while editing, so that you can see a preview of the final surface result, and aim your vertex accordingly to compensate for smoothing

Comment: I am loathe to add more vertices because it makes smoothing and correcting geometry exponentially harder.  I tried using subdiv surface in preview mode and that works ok.  I think I have to make the preview and render values for the number of subdivisions the same.